# Return statement

Tags: c#, mongodb, return

I have a problem with return statement in my c# code
I don't know what kind of data type I should use for this example, and what kind of return statement it should be

```
public async List<string> getAllData() 
{
    try 
    {
        string connectionString = "mongodb://172.16.1.24:27017";
        MongoClient client = null;
        client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        MongoServer server = null;
        server = client.GetServer();
        MongoDatabase database = null;
        database = server.GetDatabase("kljenti");
        var Client = new MongoClient();
        var DB = Client.GetDatabase("knjigoMata");

        var collection = DB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("kljenti");

        List <string> lista = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
        foreach (var kljenti in lista) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(kljenti);
        }

        return lista;

    } 
    catch 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nemogu prikazati podatke o korisnicima");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `async` your return type HAS to be either of these :

- `Task`
- `Task<T>`
- `void`

Regardless of inner code, make sure the return type confirms to any one of these.

Now if you want to return a specific datatype as your result, you might as well use Task.

Example : `Task<int>` or `Task<string>`

Read this link for further reference : [MSDN Official link for async return types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524395.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i need a return list because i need to show a that datas in griedview in another form, do you have samo instructions how to do that?

Comment: This link shows the example of exactly what you are trying to achieve : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537613(v=vs.110).aspx